# How to Calculate the Total Price of Product by Min. Quantity Order in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am working with **woocommerce** where i want to calculate the price by MOQ(Minimum Order Quantity) Attribute. If ***MOQ is 10*** and one price of product is ***Rs. 250*** then in cart price of a product will be ***250 * MQO***. If i increase the ***quantity of product to 2*** ***then product would be multiplied by MOQ.***  This is working fine but the Cart total price is showing without multiplied with MOQ.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So, where does programming come into this? This sounds to me as off-topic as purely math?

Comment: in Woocommerce cart total. price are not showing exact as by subtotal.

Comment: You need to show what you have done to resolve this so far, we need to see your broken code, else we cannot help and looks off topic as a match issue

Comment: public function get_product_subtotal( $product, $quantity ) {
  
  
  
  $moq = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_moq', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
 
$num_product =  $quantity * $moq;
$row_price        = $price * $num_product ;
$product_subtotal = wc_price( $row_price );

  return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', $product_subtotal, $product, $quantity, $num_product , $this );
 }

$product_subtotal returning real price by MOQ . But not adding in cart total price.

Comment: It needs to go into your question, formatted properly